# Clear/reset change function after click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using change for my inputs and then I'm asking questions. All of my code is inside a click function. I would like to let the user answer the questions again, and for there previous data not be there. I am new to jquery so i am not sure if my function to clear should be inside my click function, or if it has to be outside of it. I'm seeing a lot of answers to this but they are not helping me. i have added a fiddle to give you just a idea of what i am trying to do. I shortened it to just give you a idea of what i am doing, so there maybe things wrong with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/46tYs/6/embedded/result/

```
$('.myOptions').change(function () {
  $('.list').removeClass('active');
  $('.' + this.value).addClass('active');
});

$('#butt').click(function () {
  var ttta = $('.myOptions').val();
  var tt = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
});
```

My `html` code:

```
<label>Please select an option :</label>
<select class="myOptions">
  <option value="" selected>Pick an option</option>
  <option value="owner">yes</option>
  <option value="not-owner">no</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems unclear to me what your goal is.  Judging by your reset button click code, it appears like you are having trouble removing "checked" and "selected" from radio buttons and drop downs?  Here is the pertinent info:

"The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property:"

Here is the API docs explaining the difference:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Here is an example I wrote for you showing basics of getting values and resetting fields:

http://jsfiddle.net/SbB3k/

Here is a rewrite of your code, it's not optimized, but much better I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/46tYs/10/

of how to reset radio buttons and select options

Here is the gist of it:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false).val("");
$('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
$('input[type="text"]').val("");
```

Comment: my goal is to clear the inputs, my goal is for them to answer the questions i ask, and then let them do it again if they want. If i answer them again i have to backspace out all of the answers or leave the page and come back.

Comment: My code clears radio buttons and select options.  What else do you need?

Comment: if you pick the first option yes, and answer with numbers. Then hit reset it is not clearing. http://jsfiddle.net/46tYs/8/embedded/result/

Comment: I thought you could get that one by yourself, but I added the last line to take care of text inputs as well.

Comment: I'm probably a lot newer to this then you think lol. I did not get it to work, yet.

Comment: Got to my fiddle link, I broke it into three sections for you so there is no confusion.  Each individual section handles clearing a particular kind of field.

Comment: thank you for trying I appreciate it! What i am trying to do is let the user clear the form after they submit it, and do it again. Can you add the clear to my fiddle for me? I have seen a lot of good ways to clear, if i just want to clear something that is there, the problem is clearing it after the submit.

Comment: Share a fiddle with code, and I would be happy to modify it.  You just provided embedded version.